# Dynamically resizing navigation div to main content

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, resize

Greetings and Hello
I am trying to put together a wordpress site, now because the content in the main div is going to be a different height with every page I need the navigation sidebar to stretch to the same height.
So with a little javascript tom-foolery I can get the sidebar to be the same height with the following code

```
function adjust(){
    hgt=document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height=hgt+'px';

}
window.onload=adjust;
window.onresize=adjust;
```

Now that's all good for a long page but if the content is smaller then the sidebar stuff gets all messy. So I have tried an **if** statement like so

```
function adjust()
{
if (document.getElementById('content').style.height <  document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height){
hgt=document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height=hgt+'px';
else
hgt=document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('content').style.height=hgt+'px';
}
}
window.onload=adjust;
window.onresize=adjust;
```

But that just doesn't do anything, so any ideas whats going on?

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace before your else and an opening curly brace after you else. Just want to make sure it is a mistake when you copied the code here and not an actual error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

the new code if anyone needs it

```
function adjust()
{
    if (document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight < document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight)
        {
        hgt1=document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('content').style.height=hgt1+'px';
        }
        else
        {
        hgt2=document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height=hgt2+'px';
        }

}
window.onload=adjust;
window.onresize=adjust;
```

Answer (score 0):

could be several reasons:

1) as Waleed says you are missing a closure.

2) If you did not set an explicit style for

```
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height
```

it will return ""

3) Be careful assuming style.height and offsetHeight are equivalent. Depending on browsers, one or the other may be accounting for margins and paddingC: