# ASP.NET GridView vertical scrolling

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I've Grid View inside a IFrame. Its working nice when the records fit within the frame. But if I show more records then I'm unable to click on the Footer Row. It automatically goes up when I tries to scroll down. I'm using this Grid View inside the Update Panel of AJAX. Why it is happening like this? What could be the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us some code, and we might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One think is that you **do not need UpdatePanel, inside the iframe**. Iframe is by him self a self loaded and you do not need to add extra ajax to complicate the thinks. So ether leave **iframe** and remove **UpdatePanel**, ether remove **UpdatePanel** keep iframe and make a resize after the page loaf.
- One second think is to see if you have scroll bars on the iframe.
- And one third as solution to your issue, **is to recalculate the iframe size, on every reload/update**.

### How to recalculate the size

Use the **onload** on your iframe and recalculate/set the new width and height on your iframe.

The onload is fired when new content has been loaded inside the iframe.

Some similar:
  [Dynamically resizing navigation div to main content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531080/dynamically-resizing-navigation-div-to-main-content)
  [Displaying two web pages on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733337/displaying-two-web-pages-on-one-page)

On the internet you can find some example how you can get the internal width.
Here is one...

http://www.infoqu.com/dev/javascript-development/getting-iframe-width-194102-1/

```
var the_height=document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;//find the height of the internal page

var the_width=document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;//find the width of the internal page
```